# Angular service worker not working when served by .net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, service-worker

I have a small angular app with service worker (default configuration as generated by angular cli).

When I generate the bundle using "ng build --prod" and then serve it using http-server, the service worker registers and properly serves the pages when re-loading (F5). If I then shutdown the http-server, app continues to work as expected in Firefox and Chrome.

If I serve the same bundle from .net core (an application based on the angular SPA template, generated using "dotnet new angular -n MyApp"), the service worker registers and serves requests, everything looks *almost* the same, but with every F5 it also hits the .net server. When I shut down the .net server, app stops working (on F5)

To repro:

```
    dotnet new angular -n MyApp     
    ng new MyAngApp --service-worker
    ng add @angular/pwa
```

(replace the content of the ClientApp folder in the dotnet project with whatever gets generated by the angular cli)

Versions: .Net Core 2.2.102, Angular CLI 7.3.0, npm 6.4.1, node 10.15.0, http-server@0.11.1

Comment: apologies... the proper syntax is of course ng new MyAngApp and then ng add @angular/pwa

Comment: Why post that in a comment? Fix the post with an edit.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem.